# How to maintain order with respect to given constraint in multi threading?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Maybe this is a standard multi-threading problem and has a name.

A queue has list of items with each item : `{"resource" : "r1", "action" : "create"}`. Now the problem statement is to read data from this queue and process the operations in multi threaded way. But the operation with respect to particular resource should be in order.

E.g. sample input :

`[{"resource" : "r1", "action" : "create"}, {"resource" : "r2", "action" : "create"}, {"resource" : "r1", "action" : "update"}]`.

Expectation is r2 may be processed before r1 but create operation of r1 should be before update operation.

1 solution I thought and dropped was to have dedicated thread for each resource but since number of threads are limited and input is large, this will not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use Kafka so that you can perform tasks only when the previous task is completed.

Comment: A standard way would be to define a shared lock or semaphore per resource. When a task should be taken from the queue, the lock/semaphore must be acquired. If acquisition fails, skip the task and take the next one. When a task is finished, the lock/semaphore must be released.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. The name is [PriorityBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), which is thread-safe and does provide with the flexibility to declare a custom comparator of objects in the queue, in the form of a constructor argument.

Comment: PriorityBlockingQueue can be used to ensure a create starts before an update on same resource, but with >1 threads there is no guarantee that the create operation is actually completed before the update starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a driver/worker architecture here.

There would be multiple workers listening on their respective queues. Number of workers would be dependent on the volume of events.

Master's responsibility would be to read from the main queue and **map the resource field to a particular worker queue**. So this would mean that all the events/items of a resource will go only to a specific queue. This mapping of resource to particular worker could happen through some static map or hashing the resource to worker id.

This is very similar to the concept of partitioning where we use a partition key to guarantee order in particular partition.